# Unable to connect to loadbalancer public ip [service] from the openshift pod

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, openshift, k8ssandra

I have openshift cluster on which k8ssandra deployed using helm chart. I have created loadbalancer to expose service to external [Public ip is autogenerated]. I am unable to access loadbalancer ip from the pod within the same project(namespace) and seeing below error

`cassandra@k8ssandra-dc1-default-sts-0:/$ curl 52.120.130.219:9042 curl: (28) Failed to connect to 52.120.130.219 port 9042: Connection timed out`

Here is my service.yml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8ssandra-service-lb-svc
  namespace: k8ssandra-test
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9042
  selector:
    cassandra.datastax.com/cluster: k8ssandra
    cassandra.datastax.com/datacenter: dc1
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP:
```

*For short term solution, I have created VSI(Virtual Server) within the same VPC and ssh to VSI and connected to loadbalancer ip , it worked and able to perform operations.*

***But my requirements are to access loadbalancer ip from the pod within the cluster and also access from the outside network.***

Please assist me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using a LoadBalancer type of service. So, you are running in a cloud. what cloud? is port 9042 opened for LB from the outside world?

Comment: Yes Port is open in the Security Group and I am using IBM CLOUD

Comment: Dont you have `networkPolicy` in the `k8ssandra-test` namespace?

Comment: @PriyaRani Are you able to solve the problem? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Not yet, but as a workaround created public nlb to expose the service and able to connect..... however need exact solution why it is unable to connect using app load balancer.